# spark-redshift takes a lot of time to write to redshift

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-redshift

I am working on setting up spark streamer with kinesis and redshift. I read data from kinesis after every 10 sec, process it and write it to redshift using spark-redshift lib.

The problem is it is taking hell lot of time to write only 300 rows.

This is what it shows me in the console

```
[Stage 56:====================================================> (193 + 1) / 200]
```

Looking at my logs df.write.format is doing this.

I have spark setup on a machine with 4 gb ram and 2 core amazon EC2, running with --master local[*] mode.

Here is how I create stream

```
kinesisStream = KinesisUtils.createStream(ssc, APPLICATION_NAME, STREAM_NAME, ENDPOINT, REGION_NAME, INITIAL_POS, CHECKPOINT_INTERVAL, awsAccessKeyId =AWSACCESSID, awsSecretKey=AWSSECRETKEY, storageLevel=STORAGE_LEVEL)    
CHECKPOINT_INTERVAL = 60
storageLevel = memory

kinesisStream.foreachRDD(writeTotable)
def WriteToTable(df, type):
    if type in REDSHIFT_PAGEVIEW_TBL:
        df = df.groupby([COL_STARTTIME, COL_ENDTIME, COL_CUSTOMERID, COL_PROJECTID, COL_FONTTYPE, COL_DOMAINNAME, COL_USERAGENT]).count()
        df = df.withColumnRenamed('count', COL_PAGEVIEWCOUNT)

        # Write back to a table

        url = ("jdbc:redshift://" + REDSHIFT_HOSTNAME + ":" + REDSHIFT_PORT + "/" +   REDSHIFT_DATABASE + "?user=" + REDSHIFT_USERNAME + "&password="+ REDSHIFT_PASSWORD)

        s3Dir = 's3n://' + AWSACCESSID + ':' + AWSSECRETKEY + '@' + BUCKET + '/' + FOLDER

        print 'Start writing to redshift'
        df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift").option("url", url).option("dbtable", REDSHIFT_PAGEVIEW_TBL).option('tempdir', s3Dir).mode('Append').save()

        print 'Finished writing to redshift'
```

please let me know the reason for taking this much time

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have had similar experiences when writing to Redshift both through Spark and directly. spark-redshift will always write the data to S3 and then use the Redshift copy function to write the data to the target table. This approach is the best practice and the most efficient way to write large numbers of records. This approach also imposes a lot of overhead on writes, particularly when the number of records on each write is relatively small.

Looking at the output above, it appears that you have a large number of partitions (probably 200 or so).  This is likely because the `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` setting is set to 200 by default. You can find more details [in the Spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#other-configuration-options).

The group operation is probably generating 200 partitions. This means that you are doing 200 separate copy operations to S3 with each having the substantial associated latency in getting the connection and completing the write.

As we discussed in the comments below, and in chat, you can coalesce the result of the group by into fewer partitions making the following change to the line above:

```
df = df.coalesce(4).withColumnRenamed('count', COL_PAGEVIEWCOUNT)
```

This will reduce the number of partitions from 200 to 4 and the amount of overhead from the copies to S3 by a couple of orders of magnitude. You can experiment with the number of partitions to optimize performance.  You could also change the `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` setting to reduce the number of partitions given the size of data your are dealing with and the number of available cores.

Comment: Dont you thing writing only 3 rows is taking around 4 min is hell lot of time. Also even if i have 5000 rows to write, still 4 min is a lot of time

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize it was taking that long. In that case, what might be happening is that you have too many partitions (that seems to be the case from the output above). This could be causing a bottleneck on writing from your machine to S3. I am not sure if this will work with streaming, but for regular spark jobs, something like df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift").option("url", url).option("dbtable", REDSHIFT_PAGEVIEW_TBL).option('tempdir', s3Dir).mode('Append').save() would work. You can play with the number of partitions to coalesce to.

Comment: I tried that, using coalesce(4) and cache but it took the same time. it is strange but 4 min is like a lot more to write 10 records or 1000 records. I tried contacting AWS but it was also no help. Tried loading csv directly from s3 to redshift using commands to see if that was taking time, but that was also few seconds.

Comment: can you help me out, on how can I debug this. writing logs somewhere to find out where it is taking more time. It is df.save for sure that is the culprit, but where?

Comment: I will take a look at the log output if you post it somewhere. This is strange indeed.

Comment: Do you want driver and executor log output both?

Comment: Its the work directory in executor that you want rite?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The log from driver could also be useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105389/discussion-between-demetrikots-and-nipun).

Comment: Note that in the chat the coalesce did actually work, there was just a typo in Nipun's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you are databrick API. It is known issue. I had a same issue. I did talk to the Databric API team. It seems redshift is not giving good performance when loading from Avaro file. We did talk with AWS team. They are working on it. Databrick API is creating avaro file on S3 and then copy command will load avaro file. That is performance killer.

Comment: Please post this as a comment